# Move "n" files in Seperate Folder with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have found a PowerShell script which is capable of moving 'n' number of files from 'D:\source' to 'E:\Dest' directory. It will take the first 'n' number of files in the source folder and move them to the specified subfolder. It can create folders as long as they are needed.

Code:

```
$filesperfolder = 150
$sourcePath = "D:\source"
$destPath = "E:\Dest"
$i = 0;
$folderNum = 1;


Get-ChildItem "$sourcePath\*.jpg" | % {

    New-Item -Path ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum) -Type Directory -Force
    Move-Item $_ ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum);

    $i++;

    if ($i -eq $filesperfolder){
        $folderNum++;
        $i = 0 ;
    }
}
```

So far this script is working fine but, how do I set its working directory. I mean, if the script is on 'C:\test' folder, then it should search that current folder for '*.jpg' files and create folders on that same directory.

Comment: Sorry but SO is not a script writing service. We are volunteers here to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. I suggest you break up your requirements into individual parts and test that way. If you get stuck on a specific issue provide and [mvce] on what you were doing and we will gladly help you.

Comment: Sorry for asking question like that. I thought it would be helpful for others to understand.

Comment: You ask others to make your script without trying by yourself first...

Comment: I tried this scrip by myself. It still working. I just need to change few thing. Thats why i ask help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it may operate from C:\Test, you are still providing full addresses to other locations so as long as it has access and permission to those files in D:\Source and E:\Dest, it won't touch anything to do with C:\Test except for run from that location. What is your intention, you haven't actually asked us for any help with anything.

If you want to set the working directory you would use this:

```
Set-Location "D:\SourceFiles"
```

This way, regardless of where you started your script from, it would work from 'D:\SourceFiles'.

Answer (score 0):

Updated with comment.

```
$filesperfolder = 150
$sourcePath = "D:\source"
$destPath = "E:\Dest"
$i = 0;
$folderNum = 1;
$location = "D:\SourceFiles"

Get-ChildItem "$sourcePath\*.jpg" | % {

    Set-Location $location
    New-Item -Path ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum) -Type Directory -Force
    Move-Item $_ ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum);

    $i++;

    if ($i -eq $filesperfolder){
        $folderNum++;
        $i = 0 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The easy way in powershell would be the following script:

```
$source= Get-ChildItem D:\source\\*.jpeg| select -first 3 ##this would move the first three jpeg files in the folder.
foreach($line in $source.fullname){Move-Item -Path $line -Destination E:\Dest}
```