# Moving multiple images types to new folders

Tags: image, powershell, directory, move

When I have over 500 images in a folder it causes the software I'm using to view them to slow down dramatically. I've found a script that can create a new folder for every 500 and move a single image type accordingly. I'd like to figure out how to make the script search for multiple file types. Basically look for jpegs and tiffs, count them up to 500 and move that block into a new folder.

I tried adding a second search for jpegs but that caused it to go through the tiffs first and then the jpegs. I also tried creating a variable called $extensions = '*.jpg', '*.tif' but that didn't do anything.

```
$filesperfolder = 500
$sourcePath = "C:\Cases\Chiles v Karuna Murray\Documents\C - Barnes-Jewish Hospital"
$destPath = "C:\Cases\Chiles v Karuna Murray\Documents"
$i = 0;
$folderNum = 1;

Get-ChildItem "$sourcePath\*.tiff" | % {

New-Item -Path ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum) -Type Directory -Force
Move-Item $_ ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum);

$i++;

if ($i -eq $filesperfolder){
    $folderNum++;
    $i = 0 ;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Whatever comes with Windows 10

Comment: Your question looks like an exact duplicate of [move-n-files-in-seperate-folder-with-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334089/move-n-files-in-seperate-folder-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Modification of (your) script moving files in chunks of `$filesperfolder`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\12\SO_55655155.ps1
$filesperfolder = 500
$sourcePath     = "C:\Cases\Chiles v Karuna Murray\Documents\C - Barnes-Jewish Hospital"
$destPath       = "C:\Cases\Chiles v Karuna Murray\Documents"
$Extensions     = '*.tiff','*.jpg','*.jpeg'
$folderNum = 1

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Include $Extensions -File

for ($i=0;$i -le $Files.Count; $i+=$filesperfolder){
    $Selection = $Files | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First $filesperfolder
    $NewFolder = Join-Path $destPath $folderNum
    New-Item -Path $NewFolder -Type Directory -Force
    $Selection | Move-Item -Destination $NewFolder -WhatIf
    $foldernum++
}
```

To test I'd choose a different `$destPath` and a lower `$filesperfolder` number

When output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

To have an alternative folder naming:

```
0001-0500
0501-1000
1001-1500
...
```

Use this line instead:

```
$NewFolder = Join-Path $destPath ("{0:D4}-{1:D4}" -f ($i+1),($i+500))
```